# Physics : Light

Tags: visible-light

Let us assume that 4 person s are sitting on 4 corner of square ABCD. All have their eye on same level from ground.person looks person diagonally. Now when light goes from A toC and B to D then rays must intersect . so there is interference so result would be very different appearance for diagonal persons. But it is not true why

Comment: Why should there be interference?

Comment: Lack of coherence.

Answer (score 1):

Interference would only occur at the point of intersection of the light waves. However, as the light waves cross the point of intersection and reach the eyes of the observer they will no longer overlap and hence will not interfere with each other.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the down vote is because of your mention of coherence.  There's no mention in the OP of the nature of the source, so you can't make any inference about coherence.  If you delete everything before the phrase "interference would only occur" then your answer would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Light rays do not scatter off each other. If two light rays shine through each other they will emerge from the meeting point unchanged.

Interference occurs in the region where the light rays overlap but disappears outside this area. When interference does occur it just affects the energy that can be transferred to some other object like a photographic plate or CCD detector. It is not changing the light rays. If your observers were sitting in the centre of the square where the light rays meet then interference would affect the light intensity recorded on their retina, but as long as they stay outside the meeting point they see no difference in the light.